# How to remove broken bolt in Chain Tug?

Tags: repair, chain-tug

[image]

It is now stuck very hard because I used apparently too much force to tighten it, how would you take that out? The bolt is in soft aluminium frame so it can be quite tricky thing to do. Some bolt removal tool?

Related question [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3449/what-is-the-technical-name-for-this-nut-bolt-thing-with-inner-hubs) with the chain-tug -suggestion.

Comment: ...perhaps just pliers, well it is a bit tricky. There is not much space for the pliers to twist...

Comment: How is the chain tug bolt in the frame (vs in the removable/replaceable) tug?

Comment: @hhh - Good question, I think we've all had situations like this! May I assume that this is the axle bolt? Is it stuck on both sides, or just the one side?

Comment: For those missing more context, it looks like @hhh has a Genetic chain tensioner, which is a semi- (total?) clone of the [On-One chaintug](http://www.on-one.co.uk/i/q/FSOOCT/on_one_chaintug).

Comment: @lantius: yes looks the same as mine, I had to file off a tud as instructed by moz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you should just be able to remove the chain using a chain tool, and then slide the wheel back in the dropout.  This would free the chaintug from the back of the dropout, then you could rotate it down out of the way and be free to slide the wheel forward and remove it.  Once the wheel's out, take the chaintug off the axle and have the full suite of machine tools available to drill out or otherwise remove and replace the broken bolt at your leisure.

Comment: +1 yes this is clever! I immediately considered pliers/etc/more-aggresive-ways, this will keep the frame in better condition for sure. Good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Craftsman robo grips pliers. Kind of a cross between channel locks and vice grips. They really help with enough force and grip to get broken bolts lose.

Answer (score 0):

Sure would be great to have some more pics of the larger scenario but I'm assuming we are looking at the axle bolt and the wheel is stuck in the frame. Here's some things to try:

- Use a small piece of 2x4 place it on top of the tensioner and use a hammer to come down on it. If that doesn't work hit it from the bottom.
- Putting a bit of grease in there can't hurt, and if there are cracks it might help a lot.
- A heating implement to expand the metal on the tensioner may open up the hole. Try a soldering iron, or a propane torch.
- Bolt cutter or hack saw to the axle between the frame and the hub (if you can make room, loosening the other side should help.
- Drill out the inside of the bolt and it will collapse.