# What to put after taking off rear stabilisers from child bicyle?

Tags: children

I removed rear stabilisers from my 9y old daughter's bike a while ago, but I lost the little pieces that are supposed to replace the stabilisers.

Today I don't even remember what they look like. Any idea what these pieces are, meaning their name & specs (if they're standard) so I can maybe order them on Amazon?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You mean the nuts??

Comment: They are (probably) standard rear axle nuts, available at any bike shop. Probably, because children's bikes may use non-standard parts. And by no means let your child on the bike like this.

Comment: It looks like a nice bike - don't be tempted to discard it over something minor like this.  You can fix it !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want a washer and a nut on each side. Take it down to your local bike shop or hardware store to find the right size.  Any other parts that were on there were specifically on there for the stabilizers (training wheels).  Training wheels usually have a retaining mechanism that stops them from twisting, but this piece isn't needed once you remove the training wheels.

Answer (score 3):

As Kibbee said, it's simply a washer and nut threaded on the axle each side.

There is a few different thread sizes in use on inexpensive bikes - see [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/35450/24228). You can run into a problem because two common thread sizes are very similar but not compatible.

> 3/8 inch x 24 tpi Some solid axle bikes, including coaster brake
>   3/8 inch x 26 tpi Solid rear axle
>   10mm x 1mm Most quick release rear axles
>   10mm x 26 tpi Rear axle, quick release, Campganolo®>
>
> Note that the difference between 24 and 26 tpi is small and can be subtle, meaning that if you're using a spanner to do the nut up you can wreck the nut without really noticing that anything is wrong. The symptom is often that the nut strips before ever becoming tight. To avoid this put the nut on by hand until it is [completely on] the axle [thread]. If it still spins freely it is the right thread pitch.

It's best to go to a local bike repair shop to get the correct nuts. two washers and nuts are not expensive. Bear in mind you'll also have to make sure the nuts are done up tightly enough (which can be difficult if you don't have the proper wrench), tension the chain and align the wheel properly.

Comment: If OP does not have the proper wrench he should invest in one, once he has the nuts so he can know the wrench size.

Comment: And if you aren’t sure how to “align the wheel,” pay the bike shop to do it.

Comment: I should have added in my question: I can't bring it to the bike shop because it doesn't fit into my super small car :/

Comment: @drake Go to a bike store with the photos you posted, they perhaps can give you a few different nuts to try.